# CUDA - Separate min/max of (x,y,z) components of float3 array?

Tags: c++, cuda, max, min, minmax

I have an array of float3 points on a CUDA device. I would like to quickly find the min and max values (separately) of the x, y, and z components.

I know there already exist a vast number of implementations to find the min/max values for arrays using reduction algorithms, but I can't find any that perform the same operation on multi-component variables, or provide the option to supply a stride.

Does anyone know of any existing implementations that would perform this operation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a method using thrust and custom comparators,

For anyone wishing to do something similar, you can do the following. On my machine, the performance is > 10x better on data sets larger than 10 million elements:

```
// Comparators
struct comp_float3_x{
    __host__ __device__
        bool operator()(const float3& lhs, const float3& rhs){
        return lhs.x < rhs.x;
    } 
};

struct comp_float3_y {
    __host__ __device__
        bool operator()(const float3& lhs, const float3& rhs) {
        return lhs.y < rhs.y;
    }
};

struct comp_float3_z {
    __host__ __device__
        bool operator()(const float3& lhs, const float3& rhs) {
        return lhs.z < rhs.z;
    }
};

void getMinMaxDeviceFloat3(Vec3i& min, Vec3i& max, const DeviceArray<float3>& points)
{
    // Thrust does not deal with raw pointers well, wrapping is necessary
    thrust::device_ptr<float3> ptr = thrust::device_pointer_cast(points.ptr());
    thrust::pair<thrust::device_ptr<float3>, thrust::device_ptr<float3>> minmax_x = thrust::minmax_element(thrust::device, ptr, ptr + occupied_voxels, comp_float3_x());
    thrust::pair<thrust::device_ptr<float3>, thrust::device_ptr<float3>> minmax_y = thrust::minmax_element(thrust::device, ptr, ptr + occupied_voxels, comp_float3_y());
    thrust::pair<thrust::device_ptr<float3>, thrust::device_ptr<float3>> minmax_z = thrust::minmax_element(thrust::device, ptr, ptr + occupied_voxels, comp_float3_z());

    // Host buffers
    float3  min_x_host, min_y_host, min_z_host, max_x_host, max_y_host, max_z_host;

    // Copy data to host
    cudaMemcpy(&min_x_host, minmax_x.first.get(), sizeof(float3), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaMemcpy(&min_y_host, minmax_y.first.get(), sizeof(float3), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaMemcpy(&min_z_host, minmax_z.first.get(), sizeof(float3), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaMemcpy(&max_x_host, minmax_x.second.get(), sizeof(float3), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaMemcpy(&max_y_host, minmax_y.second.get(), sizeof(float3), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaMemcpy(&max_z_host, minmax_z.second.get(), sizeof(float3), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    // Assign output
    min[0] = (int)min_x_host.x;
    min[1] = (int)min_y_host.y;
    min[2] = (int)min_z_host.z;
    max[0] = (int)max_x_host.x;
    max[1] = (int)max_y_host.y;
    max[2] = (int)max_z_host.z;
}
```

Comment: Three separate calls and three passes through the data seems terribly inefficient

Comment: Well it's an order of magnitude faster than doing it on the CPU, but you're right, it's slower than it could be. I was just using the built-in templates from thrust, but it's probably possible to write a custom method which outputs a vector of 3 pairs.

Comment: Having gone through the thrust code, there is no other way. To get 3 different min-max pairs, you must perform 3 separate parallel reductions.

Comment: You could convert 3 algorithm calls to 2 algorithm calls using `thrust::reduce` and having the first find the max of all 3 components, and the second find the min of all 3 components.  With a bit more effort it may be possible to get it down to one algorithm call in thrust.  Your question doesn't seem to specify using thrust, so it ordinary CUDA it would be straightforward to do everything in a single kernel call.

Comment: The problem is the binary predicate will only yield a comparison between one component, X, Y, or Z. From what I can tell, it's not possible to pass three independent binary predicates to one parallel reduction, or at very least easily with off the shelf thrust functions/components. But regular CUDA, I'm sure given time I could implement something. Was just hoping for something more turnkey.